# Polling Control in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net, polling, voting

I want to make a voting control that allow the user to vote on one option and view the result , I don't know if there is a ready made controls that make that in ASP.NET or JavaScript, or I have to build it from scratch, please if any one can help me. I will be thankful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This tutorial may help:

> ## [Build a Poll System in ASP.NET](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Poll-Application.aspx) <sup><sub><sup>[mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20140325112535/http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Poll-Application.aspx)</sup></sub></sup>
>
> There are many websites that have polls on their front page where users (anonymous and members) give their opinions. You should also have noticed that although you are an anonymous user, you are not allowed to vote more than once. In this article, we will look at how to design a polling system, having a back-end to insert new polls along with their answers as well as how to process and store the votes of the users. We will be using stored procedures extensively for interacting with MS SQL 2005 tables.